# Как дебажить js после сборки в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, отладка, модули

товарищи! Впервые настроил webpack, собираю js из модулей в один файл. Столкнулся с вопросом, как собственно дебажить получившийся код?
Есть sourcemap, через который видно в каком модуле ошибка, но как например поставить брейкпоинт и пробежаться построчно по коду. Есть ли такая возможность?
И как вообще делаются подобные вещи в front-end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По sourcemap по большей части работает.

Если не работает:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false
},
```

sourcemap можно отключать в настройках девелопер-тулс (F12 -> F1).