# webpack (react + typeScript + redux(.tsx)) sourceMap не работает

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

**react.development.js:315**      Warning: ... карта дает массив warning-ов а не указывает конкретно то место где и начался warning в моем коде

есть

- tsconfig где "sourceMap": true,
- в webpack.config devtool:'source-map'
- внутри компонентов в том же tsx console.log('') ведет на мой код(карта работает)

При выполнении код ошибки ведет непонятно куда, а не в мой код, не на ту строку где была ошибка.

Comment: какая проблема, не работает что: карта, или сборка , или рантайм?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov при рантайм код ошибки ведет на черт знает куда не в мой код не на ту строку где была ошибка

Comment: Если source-map работает некорректно, его можно временно быключить в "инструментах разработчика chrome" -> F1 -> Sources

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov спс проверю

Comment: @Qwertiy можете пояснить каким местом мой вопрос дубликат того вопроса? я не про ошибку писал а про то что source map ведет черт знает куда

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос не про "key в React", а про "что делать, если sourceMap не работает"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168545/395779

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov по ходу конкретно эта ошибка выводит массив мест в коде где эта ошибка хоть что то затронула (в этом массиве есть путь до моего кода) просто не привычно такое видеть обычно карта ссылается сразу к ошибке в коде

Comment: Если из-за этого: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop", то я не знаю способа лучше, чем посмотреть, у всех ли реакт элементов есть key, и что он разный у всех братьев-элементов.

Comment: @Sergeikirjanov да пока что начинаю с реактом работать это первый пока что случай когда карта так реагирует ... пока что приму так как есть потом если узнаю почему или как можно получить только часть моего кода с ошибкой кину сам ответ

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, я совершенно не вижу по вопросу, что что-то не работает.

Comment: @Armen, если вопрос не про key, то совершенно непонятно, про что он. И тут есть куча других причин, чтобы его закрыть.

Comment: @Armen, у вас сейчас приложение работает и дает warning или не работает? что-то нехорошее в консоли есть кроме этого warning-а?

Comment: у меня все работает) warning исправить легко я же уже сказал что карта ведет в конец ошибки а не в то место где ошибка началась, и если раскрыть этот массив  ошибок только тогда можно найти из 15+ warning-ов ту которая справацировала все это

Answer (score 2):

Если source-map работает некорректно, его можно временно быключить в "инструментах разработчика chrome" -> F1 -> Sources